# Mapping array of objects inside parent object - Mantle iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, github-mantle

I have some json data that looks something like this:

```
    {
       items: [
                { // object 1
                  aProperty: "aValue",
                  anotherProperty: "anotherValue",
                  anObjectProperty: {}
                 },
                 { //object 2
                  aProperty: "aValue",
                  anotherProperty: "anotherValue",
                  anObjectProperty: {}
                 } 
       ]
    }
```

I want to map this json into an array of two objects using Mantle.

This would look like the following:

```
    @interface MyObject : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myProperty;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *anotherProperty;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *anObject;

    @end

    @implementation MyObject

    + (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
        return @{
                 @"myProperty": @"myProperty",
                 @"anotherProperty" : @"anotherProperty",
                 @"anObject": @"anObject"
                 };
    }

    @end
```

However, this would require me to go and find the "items" key in the json, then parse what is inside of that key.

Instead, I want Mantle to just map the whole object for me. So, I came up with this solution:

```
    @interface MyObjects : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

    @property (nonatomic) NSArray *items;

    @end

    @implementation MyObjects

    + (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
        return @{
                 @"items": @"items"
                 };
    }

    + (NSValueTransformer *)itemsJSONTransformer
    {
        return [NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:[MyObject class]];
    }

    @end
```

When's is all set and done, this will leave me this something like the following

```
NSArray *myArrayOfObjects = (MyObjects*)myobjects.items;
```

This is all great, but i believe the creation of a "MyObjects" class, just to be a placeholder for an array of MyObject is overkill. Is there a better solution? Ideally, I'm looking for a setting in mantle (or something that's easier than creating two classes just to get an array of objects) that handles the root "item" key for me, so that when this parses, it just comes out as an array of 2 objects.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a better solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

In the place where we map Jsonobject in MTLJSONAdapter

if, the json is of object type, the object should be mapped as

```
object = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:responseType fromJSONDictionary:jsonObject error:&error];
```

if the json is of array type, the object should be mapped as

```
object = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:responseType fromJSONArray:jsonObject error:&error];

[
       {
                { // object 1
                  aProperty: "aValue",
                  anotherProperty: "anotherValue",
                  anObjectProperty: {}
                 },
                 { //object 2
                  aProperty: "aValue",
                  anotherProperty: "anotherValue",
                  anObjectProperty: {}
                 } 
       }
       {
                { // object 1
                  aProperty: “bValue",
                  anotherProperty: "anotherValue",
                  anObjectProperty: {}
                 },
                 { //object 2
                  aProperty: “bValue",
                  anotherProperty: "anotherValue",
                  anObjectProperty: {}
                 } 
       }
]
```

if this is the case, it can be mapped like this

```
object = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:responseType fromJSONArray:jsonObject error:&error];
```

Comment: This. One more thing, to avoid having to create the `MyObjects` class you could just use `object = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:responseType fromJSONArray:jsonObject[@"items"] error:&error]` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myArrayOfObjects = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:responseType
                                            fromJSONArray:jsonObject[@"items"] 
                                                    error:&error]
```

Comment: Try to also add some explanation to the answer. Code only answers are usually regarded as low quality ones.